TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor in React-Quill with Quill Mention Module
I'm encountering an error while integrating the quill-mention module with react-quill in a Next.js application.  The error message I see is:
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor

Call Stack
SnowTheme.addModule
(node_modules/react-quill/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js (6130:0))
SnowTheme.addModule
(node_modules/react-quill/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js (6774:0))
eval
(node_modules/react-quill/node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js (6122:0))
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
SnowTheme.init

Here is how I’m trying to use the quill-mention module:
"use client";
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Quill from "quill";
import Mention from "quill-mention";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import TooltipCommon from "@/components/common/TooltipCommon";
import { useCopywriterStore } from "@/Store/CopywriterStore";
import { useUserStore } from "@/Store/UserStore";
import { useEditorStore } from "@/Store/EditorStore";

// Dynamically import ReactQuill to prevent SSR issues
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import("react-quill"), { ssr: false });

interface QuillEditorProps {
  customerId: string | string[];
  updateId: string | string[];
  indicatorText: string | string[];
  handleEdit: string | string[];
  orderId: string | string[];
  productFlowId: string | string[];
  leadId: string | string[];
  technicalId: string | string[];
  copywriterId: string | string[];
  amendmentId: string | string[];
  websiteContentId: string | string[];
  setIsOpenReplyModel: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  setOpenQuill: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const QuillEditor: React.FC<QuillEditorProps> = ({
  customerId,
  setIsOpenReplyModel,
  setOpenQuill,
  updateId,
  productFlowId,
  orderId,
  technicalId,
  leadId,
  indicatorText,
  amendmentId,
  copywriterId,
  websiteContentId,
  handleEdit,
  handlesave,
  editContent,
}: any) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [fileURLs, setFileURLs] = useState<{ [key: string]: string }>({});
  const { fetchCopywriterData }: any = useCopywriterStore();
  const { fetchUsersData, userData } = useUserStore();
  const {
    fetchEditorData,
    fetchLeadsEditorData,
    fetchOrderEditorData,
    fetchTechnicalUpdateData,
    fetchAmendmentUpdateData,
    fetchProductFlowUpdateData,
    fetchWebsiteContentUpdateData,
    orderEditorData,
    fetchCopywriterUpdateData,
    editorData,
    addReplyData,
    addUpdateData,
    loading,
  }: any = useEditorStore();

  const handleClear = () => {
    setValue("");
  };

  const handleChanges = (value: string, editorData: any) => {
    setValue(() =>
      editorData.getText().trim() === "" && value === "" ? "" : value
    );
  };

  const handleAddData = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ((value !== "" && value !== "<p><br></p>") || images.length > 0) {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("content", value);
        images.forEach((image) => formData.append("files", image));
        const requests = [];

        if (indicatorText === "post") {
          requests.push(
            orderId && baseInstance.post(`/updates/order/${orderId}`, formData),
            productFlowId &&
              baseInstance.post(
                `/updates/productflow/${productFlowId}`,
                formData
              ),
            customerId &&
              baseInstance.post(`/updates/customer/${customerId}`, formData),
            leadId && baseInstance.post(`/updates/lead/${leadId}`, formData),
            technicalId &&
              baseInstance.post(
                `/updates/technicaltracker/${technicalId}`,
                formData
              ),
            copywriterId &&
              baseInstance.post(
                `/updates/copywritertracker/${copywriterId}`,
                formData
              ),
            websiteContentId &&
              baseInstance.post(
                `/updates/newwebsitecontent/${websiteContentId}`,
                formData
              ),
            amendmentId &&
              baseInstance.post(`/updates/amendment/${amendmentId}`, formData)
          );
        }

        if (indicatorText === "reply") {
          requests.push(
            baseInstance.post(`/updates/update/reply/${updateId}`, formData)
          );
        }

        const responses = await Promise.all(requests.filter(Boolean));
        responses.forEach((response) => {
          if (response.status === 201) {
            successToastingFunction(response?.data?.message);
            fetchEditorData(customerId);
            fetchOrderEditorData(orderId);
            fetchLeadsEditorData(leadId);
            fetchTechnicalUpdateData(technicalId);
            fetchCopywriterUpdateData(copywriterId);
            fetchAmendmentUpdateData(amendmentId);
            fetchProductFlowUpdateData(productFlowId);
            fetchWebsiteContentUpdateData(websiteContentId);
            setIsOpenReplyModel(false);
            setOpenQuill(false);
            handleClear();
            setImages([]);
            setValue("");
          }
          fetchEditorData(customerId);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        errorToastingFunction(error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      errorToastingFunction("Please enter text or upload an image to submit.");
    }
  };

  const handleFileUpload = (files: FileList | null) => {
    if (files) {
      const fileList = Array.from(files);
      setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, ...fileList]);

      fileList.forEach((file) => {
        if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            const img = `<img src="${reader.result}" alt="${file.name}" />`;
            setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + img + `</br>`);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          setFileURLs((prev) => ({ ...prev, [file.name]: url }));
          const link = `<a href="${url}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${file.name}</a>`;
          setValue((prevValue) => prevValue + link + `</br>`);
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const inputImage = document.createElement("input");
    inputImage.setAttribute("type", "file");
    inputImage.setAttribute(
      "accept",
      "image/*, video/*, .pdf, .xlsx, .doc, .docx"
    );
    inputImage.setAttribute("multiple", "true");
    inputImage.click();

    inputImage.onchange = (e) => {
      handleFileUpload(inputImage.files);
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      Object.values(fileURLs).forEach((url) => URL.revokeObjectURL(url));
    };
  }, [fileURLs]);

  // Commented out because it causes an error
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (Quill) {
  //     Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);
  //     Quill.register("modules/mention", Mention);
  //   }
  // }, [Quill]);

  const toolbarOptions = [
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
    [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }],
    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }, { list: "check" }],
    [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }],
    [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }],
    [{ direction: "rtl" }],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
    [{ font: [] }],
    [{ align: [] }],
  ];

  const options = {
    debug: "info",
    modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions,
      imageResize: {
        parchment: Quill.import("parchment"),
        modules: ["Resize", "DisplaySize"],
      },
      mention: {
        allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\s]*$/,
        mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
        source: async (
          searchTerm: string,
          renderItem: (data: any[]) => void
        ) => {
          try {
            await fetchUsersData(); // Ensure data is fetched first
            const filteredUsers = userData
              .filter((user: any) =>
                user.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              )
              .map((user: any) => ({ value: user.name }));
            renderItem(filteredUsers);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching mention users:", error);
            renderItem([]);
          }
        },
      },
    },
    placeholder: "Compose an epic...",
    theme: "snow",
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddData} className="flex gap-2 flex-col ">
        <div className="">
          <ReactQuill
            placeholder={options.placeholder}
            theme={options.theme}
            modules={options.modules}
            value={value}
            onChange={(value, _, __, editor) => {
              handleChanges(value, editor);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-start gap-2 items-center">
          <Button
            type="submit"
            className="cursor-pointer h-[24px] rounded-lg border border-primary bg-primary px-4 text-white transition hover:bg-opacity-90"
          >
            {isLoading ? (
              <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-6 w-6 animate-spin text-[#fff]" />
            ) : indicatorText === "reply" ? (
              "Reply"
            ) : (
              "Update"
            )}
          </Button>

          <div onClick={imageHandler} className="w-fit cursor-pointer ">
            <TooltipCommon text="Add Files">
              <div className="hover:bg-gray-100 px-2 py-1 rounded">
                <AddFilesDarkUIconSVG />
              </div>
            </TooltipCommon>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default QuillEditor;


I've integrated the quill-mention module into my react-quill component but am running into an issue. The error TypeError: moduleClass is not a constructor appears, and the call stack indicates a problem with SnowTheme.addModule in the Quill.js file.
I've tried to register the module as follows:
useEffect(() => {
  if (Quill) {
    Quill.register("modules/imageResize", ImageResize);
    Quill.register("modules/mention", Mention);
  }
}, [Quill]);


However, this causes the mentioned error. I've also commented out the registration as it seems to be the cause of the issue.
What I've Tried:
Ensuring that the quill-mention module is correctly imported and used.
Checking the version compatibility of react-quill, quill, and quill-mention.
Referencing the Quill documentation for proper module registration.
What I Need Help With:
Why am I encountering this TypeError?
How can I properly integrate the quill-mention module with react-quill?
Are there any additional steps or configurations required to avoid this error?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
